# Don't restart service more than 1 time within 60 seconds inotify

Tags: bash, httpd.conf, inotify

I Have a script which restart httpd service if file is changed, how to implement rate control to restart service only one time within 60 seconds

I have idea what to do:

compare current time with time when log.txt was modified, but no idea how to start

```
#!/bin/bash

mypidfile=/var/run/filewatch.pid

trap "rm -f $mypidfile" EXIT

echo $$ > "$mypidfile"


stdbuf -oL inotifywait -m /home/centos -r -e modify > log.txt |
    while read path action file >> log.txt; do
        if [[ "$file" =~ .*py$ ]] || [[ "$file" =~ .*css$ ]] || [[ "$file" =~ .*html$ ]] || [[ "$file" =~ .*js$ ]] ; then # Does the file end with .py css html js
            systemctl restart httpd # If so, do your thing here!
            #touch /home/centos/log.txt
            echo "test"
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remember the last time you restarted httpd with `lasttime=$(date +%s)`
2. If the next restart is triggered, sleep up to the specified time subtracted with  the difference between the last time it was restarted and now
   `difftime=$(($(date +%s) - lasttime)); if (( difftime < 60 )); then sleep $(( 60 - difftime )); fi; lasttime=$( ... )`

So smth like:

```
    if [[.... ]] ; then # Does the file end with .py css html js

        // delay up until 60 seconds from the last restart
        if [ -n "${lasttime:-}" ]; then
             difftime=$((60 - ($(date +%s) - lasttime)))
             if ((difftime > 0)); then
                  sleep "$difftime"
             fi
        fi
        lasttime=$(date +%s)

        systemctl restart httpd # If so, do your thing here!
        #touch /home/centos/log.txt
        echo "test"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kamil Cuk's advice i solved the problem:

```
inotifywait -m /home/centos -r -e modify |
    while read path action file>>log.txt; do
        if [[ "$file" =~ .*py$ ]] || [[ "$file" =~ .*css$ ]] || [[ "$file" =~ .*html$ ]] || [[ "$file" =~ .*js$ ]] ; then # Does the file end with .py css html js
           lastreboot=$(cat last_restart.txt)
           currenttime=$(date +%s)
           let elapsed=currenttime-lastreboot
           if [ "$elapsed" -lt 60 ]; then echo "less"
           else
           echo "restarting HTTPD"
           systemctl restart httpd
           echo $(date +%s)> last_restart.txt
           fi
        fi
    done
```